# What are the working hours of Recycling Centre?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have two recycling centres with maximum number of modifications and they are constantly congested - their storage of recycled garbage is constantly full or almost full (18-20/20 tons). As a consequence, the recycled garbage trucks are full and don't pick up more garbage which then piles up on the streets.

I've been monitoring the situation a bit and it appears that the recycling centres process the garbage only during the day. Is this true / intended? What hours is the recycling centre supposed to be working?

Also, quite often the recycling centre stops working entirely.. even though it has room for alloys/plastics/metal in its "output storage" and there are trade depots with appropriate empty lots available and factories out of materials. This appears to be a bug but even when the recycling centre works, it doesn't seem to be doing anything during the night.

Or do I simply need more recycle centres? My town has population around 150k. Should I build more of them, three maybe?
A friend in the region also sent couple of his trucks, but at times it's still not enough.

The normal garbage trucks don't pick up the recycled trash, do they? It would be cool if you could get them to also pick up recycled garbage in case of any problems with recycling centres...

Comment: Btw if the recycling centre stops working entirely, closing it, waiting about an hour and re-opening it should help. If not, demolish and rebuild - this has worked for me.

Comment: I have come across the issue of recycling centers failing to work at all, I will try turning them off for an hour and see if that fixes it but demolishing and rebuilding didn't fix the problem for me

Comment: I tried to demolish/rebuild only once and it fixed it for the time being, but the problem seems to re-emerge. Yesterday I closed/reopened the recycles centres several times and mostly they were working (albeit somehow slowly)... I even turned them off in the night and re-activated around 5:00 AM, saving some money :)

Comment: Well, I did notice it's possible to have 12 recycling collection trucks while you can only have 4 recycled material delivery trucks, I am suspecting that this is one cause of the bottleneck assuming similar sort of capacities in each truck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are working hours for collection, as in the evening when you mouse over it says something like "Waiting Collection Hours to Begin" (Don't remember the exact words). However, I think the following is true:

- They still process recyclables already in material storage
- This gets buggy when you share trucks within other regions in the city, so you need to not share your trucks with other cities (If you watch the trucks you can make sure they don't leave the city after a couple days after changing the settings).
- If you have already hit this bug where the recycling center is full, you may have to destroy and rebuild your recycling center after disabling sharing
- The total number of bins builds up (not just the number collected). So when you get enough recycling centers, the total number of bins might start to go down (as the number collected goes up).
- I don't think recycling trucks pick up trash, only recycling
- More education means more recycling
- I think you might want to diversify reclamation line types within a recycling center

That being said this still doesn't work great for me, with 3 recycling centers maxed out in reclamation lines and trucks. I get only about 9k bins collected out 18k (Around 120k population).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kyle. After yesterday's update the bug appears to be fixed, at least my recycling centre was working non-stop. Also, the garbage as well as recycled garbage trucks are working day and night now; the 'waiting for collection shift to begin' appears to be gone or at least I haven't seen it.

Comment: btw I asked if _normal_ garbage trucks pick up _recycled_ trash, not the other way around. I mean, maybe it could be added as a feature, to order garbage cars to dispose recyclable trash the same way as normal trash (in case the recycling centre would lack capacity) to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Recycling center opens at around 6am and end depending on your city's size(population) 
You will need garbage collection though. If you see the lots full(common for large cities) try and build a trade PORT, as they can hold much more of the resources(i.e, metals,plastic,etc)